# Django exclude single value from query

Tags: django, django-models

Given a model, let sat MyModel,
I want to extract from it all objects associated to a certain entry and exclude all of them that contain the 'foo' world a certain field (let's say custom_name).

I've found the following solution:

```
all_entries = MyModel.objects.filter(entry=foo_entry)

for el in all_entries:
    if 'foo' in el.custom_name:
        all_entries.remove(el)
```

There is a better and more performing way to do it?

Comment: Note that your for-loop only removes the first element with 'foo' in `custom_name`, not all elements with 'foo' (since you `break` out of the loop).

Comment: I've removed the break, thank you for spotting it

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
all_entries = MyModel.objects.filter(entry=foo_entry).exclude(custom_name='foo')
```

**Edit**

If you want to exclude the items that *contain* 'foo' you can use `.exclude(custom_name__contains='foo')`

`contains` is case sensitive so the rows with the custom name of 'Foo' will not be excluded. If you want your query to be case insensitive, you can use `.exclude(custom_name__icontains='foo')`

Comment: To answer the exact question ("exclude items that **contain** the string 'foo' in `custom_name`"): `.exclude(custom_name__contains='foo')`

Comment: @dirkgroten I overlooked that detail. Added an edit to the answer to cover it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

use Q object

`from django.db.models import Q

all_entries = MyModel.objects.filter(~Q(custom_name__contains='foo'),entry=foo_entry)`

or

```
all_entries = MyModel.objects.filter(entry=foo_entry).exclude(custom_name__contains='foo')
```